# nesting a string and printing deepest nest

Tags: python

What I have is a string that looks for example like this `{[]}{([])}()`and I loop it through to find if it is an open or a close bracket and append it to the list.
What I wanna do now is to find which is the deepest nasting and print it out. So in this example i would print the middle `{([` but I am confused how to do it. I can append the beginning of the open brackets and then reset it but how to compare couple of them though, and printing the biggest one

my code:

```
def is_nested(str):
    stack = []
    deepest =[]
    index=1
    open=0
    for c in str:
        if c == "{" or c == "(" or c == "[" or c =="<":
            stack.append(c) # this is push
            deepest.append(c)
            open +=1
            index +=1
        elif c == "}":
            x = stack.pop()
            index +=1
            if x != "{":
                index -=1
                x2=parens(x)
                return "False: expected %s at character index %d, but received } instead." %(x2,index)
        elif c == "]":
            x = stack.pop()
            index +=1
            if x != "[":
                index -=1
                x2=parens(x)
                return "False: expected %s at character index %d, but received ] instead." %(x2,index)
        elif c == ">":
            x = stack.pop()
            index +=1
            if x != "<":
                index -=1
                x2=parens(x)
                return "False: expected %s at character index %d, but received > instead." %(x2,index)
        elif c == ")":
            x = stack.pop()
            index +=1
            if x != "(":
                index -=1
                x2=parens(x)
                return "False: expected %s at character index %d, but received ) instead." %(x2,index)

    check(str)
    return True
def check(str):
    deepest =[]
    for c in str:
        if c == "{" or c == "(" or c == "[" or c =="<":
            deepest.append(c)
    print deepest


def parens(x):
    if x == "<":
        return ">"
    elif x =="(":
        return ")"
    elif x == "{":
        return "}"
    elif x == "[":
        return "]"


print is_nested("{[()}")
print is_nested("([)")
print is_nested("{[]({})}")
print is_nested("<()>")
print is_nested("{(<)}")
```

Comment: do you want to find the longest sequence of opening brackets in a row?

Comment: yes and i want to print it out

Comment: I am very close, what Bula below gave me is really close, but i don't always want to append it, for example if the sequence ends and new sequence begins i want to make sure if it is smaller if larger then previous I want to make a new list out of sequence not appending it

Comment: what about `'{()([])}'`? Is the longest `'(['` or `'{(['`?

Comment: thats a good one Bula and actually I don't know lol

Comment: Well I suspected that you don't know :) Either way if its the first one then root's answer is the right choice and if it is the second one then you can go with mine.

Comment: i guess I am just gonna stick to the ones that are next to each other like '([])'

Comment: but what root gave is something impressive

Comment: The task is fairly simpler then the one when the parenthesis don't have to be successive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your wishes correctly, but this finds the  longest sequence of successive opening brackets:

```
In [20]: import re

In [21]: s = '{[]}{([])}()'

In [22]: max(re.findall("[\(\[\{]+",s),key=len)
Out[22]: '{(['
```

Comment: @JackF -- it finds all the sequences that contain only opening's and prints out the longest one...

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate and update the current number of open brackets and keep the max value that you had while looping. You can put all open brackets on a string that you use as a stack and update max with this string if the lenght is bigger than curren length of max.

```
OPEN = "<[({"
CLOSED = ">])}"
def is_nested(str):
    stack = []
    deepest =[]
    for c in str:
        if c in OPEN:
            stack.append(c)
            if len(stack)>len(deepest):
                deepest.append(c)
        elif c in CLOSED:
            x = stack.pop()
            if OPEN.index(x) != CLOSED.index(c):
                return "Error"
    return ''.join(deepest)
```

Comment: but the problem is I am not quite sure how to reset it and continue counting. also how it can be then printed out

Comment: I don't see how this can remove the previous ones for example if i have {[]}{([])}() and just want to print out {([ the middle nesting and remove the first two, as this what you gave me would only append

Comment: So you want deepest *successive* parens only?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def is_nested(nested_str):
    opening = ['(', '{', '[', '<']
    closing = {'(':')','{':'}', '[':']', '<':'>'}
    braces = []
    depth = 0
    max_depth = 0
    max_depth_index = None
    for index, char in enumerate(nested_str):
        if char in opening:
            braces.append(char)
            depth += 1
        elif char == closing[braces[-1]]:
            braces.pop()
            depth -= 1
        else:
            raise ValueError("This is not a valid str")
        if depth > max_depth:
            max_depth = depth
            max_depth_index = index
    return max_depth, max_depth_index
```

This function takes a string with only braces, and tells you the deepest level of nesting, and the index of the opening brace of the first instance of that level of nesting. As a bonus, it will raise an error if the string is miss-formed.

```
>>> is_nested('{[][]}')
(2, 1)
>>> is_nested('{[][<()()>]()}[]()')
(4, 5)
>>> is_nested('{(})')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "nesting.py", line 16, in is_nested
ValueError: This is not a valid str
```

I've defined any character other than a brace to be an error, but this could easily be changed by modifying the `else` condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_nested(in_str):
    stack = []
    deepest = tuple()

    open_b = ('(','[','{','<')
    close_b = (')',']','}','>')

    for i in in_str:
        print stack, i
        if i in open_b:
            stack.append(i)
            if len(stack) > len(deepest):
                deepest = tuple(stack)
        else:
            p = stack.pop()
            print p
            print open_b.index(p)
            print close_b[open_b.index(p)]
            if i != close_b[open_b.index(p)]:
                raise Exception('Wrongly nested')
    if len(stack) > 0:
        raise Exception('Wrongly nested')
    return deepest
```